# Good Java-Based Raster Libraries

Tags: raster, java, library

Can anyone suggest a good, Java-based raster library?  By good, I mean a library that can read common raster formats (ex. tif, img...etc) and save them to other image formats (ex. png).

I say Java-based because I am investigating a simple GIS app for Android.  I am aware that GDAL would seem like the obvious choice, but it seems like it will difficult to deploy GDAL with an Android application.  If anyone knows otherwise, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) is the Java equivalent of GDAL.

Comment: GeoTools seems to fit the bill, specifically the ImageIO-EXT.  Hopefully the GeoTools library itself can handle the formats I am interested in, without needing the GDAL plug-in, only time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

ImageIO-Ext

The ImageIO-Ext project provides extensions, fixes and improvements for the standard Java ImageIO library such as:

support the GDAL I/O library
support for reading/writing JPEG2000 files with Kakadu
improved support for reading/writing tiff files
Releases, along with the required native binary packages, can be found here: http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/